# KeyError: 'search' / request.method

Tags: python, api, post, postman

I'm using the genius api to get lyrics to appear on my webpage after typing in an artists name. However when using the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

from lyrics import scrapeLyricText
from markov import MarkovLyrics

app = Flask(__name__)


def generateArtistLyrics(name):
    songs = scrapeLyricText(name)
    m = MarkovLyrics()

    for song in songs:
        m.populateMarkovChain(song)
    return m.generateLyrics()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lyricsGenerator():
    lyrics = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        artist = request.form['search']
        lyrics = generateArtistLyrics(artist)
    return render_template('home.html', lyrics=lyrics)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and using postman to test the api call/POST request I get the following traceback:

werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'search'

line 21, in lyricsGenerator
artist = request.form['search']

However when i alter my code to the following:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lyricsGenerator():
    lyrics = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        artist = request.form.get('search', None)
        lyrics = generateArtistLyrics(artist)
    return render_template('home.html', lyrics=lyrics)
```

I no longer get a Traceback but when I input an artist name it does not show up on my webpage but the lyrics do appear in my pycharm terminal.

Here is my html file for reference as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lyrics Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Lyrics Generator</h1>
<p>Here, you can generate lyrics by the artist of your choice!</p>
<form action="{{url_for('lyricsGenerator')}}" method='POST'>
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search for an artist...">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<p>{{ lyrics }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Postman is giving a
500INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: Please [edit] to also show how are you making the request in Postman. Your route is expecting form data, but I suspect the way you make the request in Postman doesn't use form data or you constructed the form parameters wrong. Also, if you are only getting an error with Postman but not from the HTML form, then the HTML form here is irrelevant.

Comment: Is it possible to show your entire python file? It'll help me do some debugging

Comment: I added the full app.py file, pls let me know if more info is needed

Comment: Do things work on the Postman application ? , if it does then you can access Python code there its there on the right hand side,  I recommend you use Python requests, to make API calls.
If things dont work on the App, then try to debug that. once things work there access the code section in it to get an idea. Also share the API you are using

Comment: Repeating my [1st comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72496589/keyerror-search-request-method#comment128066836_72496589), if you say you are getting an error when you use Postman, then please [edit] to show how you make the request with Postman. A screenshot of the request showing the URL, the formd data, and the response body would make this question clearer.